# Python screen scrape whole website

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to make a little program which will use every single something-meaning word from any website
It's meant to be in python and I've heard about BeautifulSoup but I don't quite know how to use it for this purpose... little tutorial? :p
Or is it just that easy as a regex? like: 
`re.compile('<.*>(.*)<.*>')` 
so everything between the brackets?
Newlines and stuff is already done ;)

thanx in advance guys and sorry for the minor english...

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with HTML at all... and could you provide a little more information as to what every "single something-meaning word" means?

Comment: Lets say that with something meaning i mean like you would go to that website, select it all and then paste it in notapad... there's no need for a markup

Answer (score 1):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) makes web-crawling easy. It also has great documentation and `scrapy startproject` command will build a skeleton project for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is a python library that allows you to perform http requests and even provides some ability to parse the html and extract the data you are looking for.  It's major feature is that it can act like a browser and handle things like authentication and cookies.

Regex is not ideal when working with XML/HTML(you'll see). You can use BeautifulSoup in combination with mechanize if you prefer that parsing library.  Learning about things like XPath can make your life simpler as well.

Both mechanize and BeautifulSoup have tutorials out there, so start reading some code!